# Apache Ignite Cache - Gets all data from database -

Tags: java, apache-spark, caching, ignite

How I sure such a this condition always true:
Let's say I have 3 tables which are contains 1000, 2000, 3000 records.
And I have to load that all records to the cache, but I want to be sure all the data is in cache before Client using this cache.

Note that cache mode is replicated.

Apache Ignite has this future?

Here is the things that I will plan to do:

I will set the "atomicityMode" to the "TRANSACTIONAL"

I will create class for cacheStoreFactory

This class contains loadCache method extends from CacheStoreAdapter.

here is the pseducode:

```
public void loadCache(IgniteBiInClosure<K, V> clo, Object... args) {
    // Connect the all databases
    /*while true:
        try(Transaction transaction = Ignition.ignite().transactions().txStart(TransactionConcurrency.OPTIMISTIC, TransactionIsolation.SERIALIZABLE)){
            PreparedStatement for all databases such as "select * from persons"
            then take the all ResultSet from all databases
            then create the corresponding object from the results and put the  "clo.apply(objectID, object);"
            before transaction.commit()
                if there is way, find the total records number from all databases (maybe find before starting try block)
                then, again if there is way, compare the cache size and total records
                        If 2 numbers are equals -> transaction.commmit() & break
                        else -> continue;
        }

     */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use distributed data structures to signal that some action was completed. For example:

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/countdownlatch

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/distributed-semaphore

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/atomic-types

Also, you can check the size of the cache or send the message from one node to another like here:

https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/messaging/MessagingExample.java

However, until you load the data in the transaction then other nodes will not be able to read it.

Comment: "However, until you load the data in the transaction then other nodes will not be able to read it." Therefore I will be sure that all data is in cache and client(s) won't read until transaction.commit() ? . Am I right? Even if I have more than one cache nodes, because cache mode is REPLICATED?

Comment: and, could you give a simple definition of node in apache ignite or anywhere?

Comment: Looks like you have the wrong understanding what REPLICATED cache means. Cache mode REPLICATED just means that every node will contain the copy of data (like backups). https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-modes#replicated-mode It means that in case if some of the nodes go offline then other nodes will contain backup copies of data and you will not lose it. Even if cache Replicated then for the user it will be the unified cache.

Comment: You can read about nodes here - https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/clients-vs-servers

Comment: Okey, here is the full scenario, I have 1.000.000 datas and I have loaded those datas to the cache, then there is another node that wants to copy the all datas in this cache and it will serve to the client to consume. But we should be sure that, all datas aer copied before using by client, or if client wants to use, we should print that "node is not ready". How do I implement this?

Comment: How will you implement it in the regular database? I guess that client node should wait for some notification. For example, you can use some custom event notification, distributed messaging or just check the size of the cache. This is up to you. https://ignite.apache.org/features/messaging.html